# Is it possible for a DNS server to allow multiple names to point to it?

Tags: dns, web-hosting

I have a 2 DNS servers (BIND) lets say ns1.abc.com & ns2.abc.com. These name servers are the name servers for multiple domains. One of my clients, lets say xyz.com would like the name servers on there WHOIS to show ns1.xyz.com & ns2.xyz.com. Can setup my current DNS server to allow this? We tried, but some registrars wouldn't allow it saying that it was using a "HIDDEN NAME".

Any ideas?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The functionality you want to achieve is called custom/private nameservers. If your registrar allows, you can set 2 hostnames on BIND server IP addresses and register custom nameservers on your domain name.

Once they are registered, you can follow this KB to setup custom nameservers in BIND DNS server ... http://www.mysql-apache-php.com/dns-server-tutorial.htm .If you are on cPanel setup, it's pretty easy to setup custom nameservers from WHM itself.